# How do you force a line break between two words in a XAML-declared Label?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Maybe I'm not using the right key words, but all my searches are coming up empty. How do you force a line break?

I can tell you that none of the following work:

```
<Label
    Content="Line&br;Break:" />

<Label
    Content="Line<br />Break:" />

<Label
    Content="Line
    Break:" />

<Label
    Content="Line\nBreak:" />
```

Can someone share this closely guarded secret?

Thanks.

---

**EDIT:**

Okay, never mind. I *finally* found it.

```
<Label
    Content="Line&#x0a;Break:" />
```

Definitely not easy to guess!

---

**EDIT 2:**

Okay, and now to get the text to be right-justified, I went with this:

```
<Label>
    <TextBlock
        TextAlignment="Right"
        Text="Line&#x0a;Break:" />
</Label>
```

Thanks to Julien for the idea of using a TextBlock.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you only need to display text, you can use a `TextBlock` instead of a `Label`:

```
<TextBlock>
  Line<LineBreak/>Break:
</TextBlock>
```

If you really need a `Label` (e.g. you need to respond to a click event), you can wrap the above code inside a `Label`.

Comment: I don't need it to respond to a click event, but I do need it to gray out when disabled (which I believe TextBlock won't do without extra code/markup). However, I'm now having a problem trying to right justify the text of my label, so I might need to use something else. HorizontalAlignment="Right" and HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" both have no effect.

Comment: You can set the TextAlignment property of the TextBlock to Right. As for the gray out, it's going to require extra markup.

Comment: Thanks, Julien. I was able to solve by putting the TextBlock inside a Label (see my edits above).

Answer (score 10):

If you want a new line in a label:

```
<Label Content="Lorem &#10;ipsum" />
```

("10" is the ascii number for newline)

or

```
<Label Content="Lorem &#xA;ipsum" />
```

("A" is the ascii number for newline in hex)

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Label>First line</Label>
    <Label>Second line</Label>
</StackPanel>
```

If the formatting gets really involved, I'd use `FlowDocumentScrollViewer`.

Comment: This is not the intended way. Because they're separate controls, you have to deal with margins etc... (it acts more like a paragraph)
The TextBlock with LineBreaks is much cleaner!

Comment: Some advanced/custom controls don't accept that linebreak like that however. This should always work, and is at least a good alternative to keep in mind.